# Simplify the following symbolic statement

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify the following symbolic statement

$(x\gt3)\lor(x\gt10)$

The answer given is : $(x\gt3)$

Why is this the answer?

Comment: $x>10\implies x>3.$

Comment: To help you understand what this symbolic statement is about, you can make for yourself een logical table as a function of the variable x. For example for x=2 you see that the statement (x>3) is not true, hence 0. Also (x>10) is not true. Next check the case x=7. And then check x=12. Finally apply the OR operator to the results.

Answer (score 1):

The statement $(x \gt 3 ) \cup ( x \gt 10 )$ given by you, is basically  -

> $x$ is greater than 3 OR $x$ is greater than 10

written in symbolic form.

---

Now, it should be obvious to you that $( x \gt 10 ) \Rightarrow ( x\gt 3 )$ , as pointed out by @mfl in the comments. Thus, the statement reduces to

$( x \gt 3 ) \cup ( x \gt 10 ) = { x :x\ gt 3 or x \gt 10 } ={x: x\gt 3}=( x \gt 3)$

---

Now, take a look at the logic provided by @M. Wind. Once, you realize how the interaction of the two conditions with the 'OR' operator renders the second condition meaningless, the result is trivial and obvious.

Basically, whenever $x$ is greater than 10, it is already greater than 3; and the OR statement means that we only have to check for the truth of one condition, which in this case is $x\gt 3$. Another way of looking at it is that $x\gt 3 $ already contains both the conditions, allowing us to neglect $x \gt 10$ as already contained in $x\gt 3$ by virtue if the 'OR' condition.